# How do i use IEnumerable<string> as List?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
var ext = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     .Where(s => ext.Any(e => s.EndsWith(e)));
CopyFilesToClipBoard()
```

And the method CopyFilesToClipBoard()

```
public static string[] CopyFilesToClipBoard(List<string> file_list)
{
    foreach (string file_name in Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath))
        file_list.Add(file_name);
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, file_list.ToArray());
    string[] file_names = (string[])
    Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    return file_names;
}
```

The problem is that CopyFilesToClipBoard should get List but var myFiles is IEnumerable

Comment: Your `CopyFilesToClipboard` method seems to have two purposes - it adds the files in the startup path to the list, *and* it copies things to the clipboard. I'd strongly recommend that you separate the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just call the `ToList` method:

```
CopyFilesToClipBoard(myFiles.ToList());
```